# Hover effect makes unwanted changes on UI

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my first navigation bar but it's not working expected. How can I remain the main UL element and not increase their sizing if I want to hover the li element?

I tried to add in ul li a `margin:0` but still, it didn't work.

I wanted to have different styling when I hover those li, but the blue background changed as well, what I wanted is to remain the .links as is so that only the change will take effect on the li when I hover it.

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav .logo a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav .links {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    background: #00ABE4 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

nav .toggle-btn {
    color: #00ABE4 ;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.nav-btn {
    background: #00ABE4 ;
    color: #fff;
    padding:  0.5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: scale 0.2 ease-in-out;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
    scale: 1.05;
    color: #fff;
}

ul > li:hover {
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px ;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    
}

nav .nav-btn:active {
    scale: 0.95;
}
```

```html
 <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#">Jury Mini</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hero">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hero">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Get Started</a>
                <div class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></div>
            </nav>
          
        </header>
```

Comment: Decrease padding of links

Comment: What effect do you want hover to have on the element that is hovered?

Comment: I wanted to have different background on those li's without effection the main background on the menu which is brigh blue

Answer (score 3):

I added this codes to your css :

```css
ul li {
list-style-type:none
}

ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px;
}

ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px;
background: #000;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
color:#fff;
}
```

and deleted `ul > li:hover` class,  added `width:100vw` for `nav` .Finally added `justify-content:center;` `align-items:center;` to `nav .links` class

```css
nav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 60px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav .logo a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav .links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    gap: 2rem;
    background: #00ABE4 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

nav .toggle-btn {
    color: #00ABE4 ;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.nav-btn {
    background: #00ABE4 ;
    color: #fff;
    padding:  0.5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: scale 0.2 ease-in-out;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
    scale: 1.05;
    color: #fff;
}

ul li {
list-style-type:none
}

ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px;
}

ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px;
background: #000;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
color:#fff;
}


nav .nav-btn:active {
    scale: 0.95;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">Jury Mini</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="hero">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="hero">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="hero">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Get Started</a>
    <div class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This is nice! Well done!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to remove the `padding: 5px;`
that you put in the `ul>li :hover` style first the `ul` element will stay still.

Answer (score 2):

In your hover code, you add extra padding to the text, which is why this happens. Removing it will help you:

```
ul > li:hover {
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px ;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

To debug such an issue, you do the next:

- Inspect the element (right click then select inspect)
  [image]
- it will open a code editor in the browser. Select li (which is the one that you have the hover effect on it
  [image]
- go to style, click on the :hov  and choose hover to activate that effect
  [image]
- You can see the CSS style in the browser and activate/deactivate what you prefer.
  [image]

The padding property provides a padding area for your element, which is the letting the whole banner expand and is the reason causing this issue:

[image]

Here you can find further information about how to use padding and few example from MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Answer (score 1):

The only problem was the `padding: 5px ;` on the hover in your CSS. You can see my version without the padding below.

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin:  0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav .logo a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav .links {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    background: #00ABE4 ;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

nav .toggle-btn {
    color: #00ABE4 ;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.nav-btn {
    background: #00ABE4 ;
    color: #fff;
    padding:  0.5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: scale 0.2 ease-in-out;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
    scale: 1.05;
    color: #fff;
}

ul > li:hover {
    background: #000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    
}

nav .nav-btn:active {
    scale: 0.95;
}
```

```html
 <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#">Jury Mini</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="hero">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hero">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hero">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Get Started</a>
                <div class="toggle-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></div>
            </nav>
          
        </header>
```